# How to import data from textfiles to JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I have a text file that has 10 lines of information. How to copy paste that info in a JTextArea?

```
public void createPage4()
    {
    panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel4.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

    BufferedReader log=null;

        try {


        FileReader logg =new FileReader("logsheet.txt");
            log = new BufferedReader(logg); 

        textArea = new JTextArea("how do I get all the content of logsheet, I can get it on the command window as shown below");




        for (int x = 0 ; x<10; x++){

            System.out.println(log.readLine());

             }


             panel4.add(textArea);
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. Just use the read(...) method that is supported by all text components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Append()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) to copy each line you read to the end of your `JTextArea` component.

> append
>
> public void append(String str) Appends
>   the given text to the end of the
>   document. Does nothing if the model is
>   null or the string is null or empty.
>   This method is thread safe, although
>   most Swing methods are not. Please see
>   How to Use Threads for more
>   information.
>
> Parameters: str - the text to insert
>   See Also: insert(java.lang.String,
>   int)

Your for loop will become:

```
for (int x = 0 ; x<10; x++){
    textArea.append(log.readLine() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: @razshan, please explain why you would write your own code and reinvent the wheel when this functionality is already part of the API? I suppose if you ever need to write data you will also create your own write() method instead of using the method that is part of the API. This is not the way to learn how to program.

Answer (score 1):

```
textArea.read(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("logsheet.txt"), null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("logsheet.txt"));
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    textArea.append(line).append("\n");
}
reader.close();
```

Here you're reading the entire contents of the file (so it doesn't matter how many lines it has), appending the contents to a string builder and then setting the text area to the contents of the string builder. (It's also important to remember to close your reader after you've finished with it.)

The above will just append to the text area. If you want to clear it first, add `textArea.setText("");` before the while loop.

If you want to make sure only the first 10 lines are read, add a counter, increment it on each iteration of the while loop and then exit if it's 10 or above (I'll leave that as an implementation exercise if you need it!)